Sticky Sessions with SpringBoot 3.3 & Undertow?
If there were a way to provide the JSESSIONID value myself, that would solve it. Else Jvm Route seems to be the solution I’m looking for. Alas that is Spring, while nowadays our session is Jakarta. Maybe they’re not yet that well aligned? I tried adding DefaultCookieSerializer.setJvmRoute to the following:
Suggestions in https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/guides/java-custom-cookie.html alas do nothing (even changed the cookie name to check.) It vaguely says, “Spring Session must be set up, e.g. with Redis.” We override AuthenticationProvider.authenticate returning UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken. I guess that gives our JSESSIONID. But apparently that doesn’t correspond to the requirement.
I also tried autowiring HttpSessionIdResolver to get a handle. But it wasn’t injectable. Not sure if creating a Bean myself would be a viable path?
Undertow also calls this concept Jvm Route, and has a handler for that. But the constructor JvmRouteHandler​ requires me to pass in an HttpHandler. It seems this chains handlers to do all the stuff necessary. But (assuming I manage to add this,) where would I get the handler to chain to?
In the past we had JBoss and used Undertow Expression Language to rewrite the cookie. When switching to SpringBoot with Undertow, I was bewildered about where I might activate and configure Undertow’s (not to be confused with SpringBoot’s) Expression engine? So instead I fronted with Apache. But that has various drawbacks.
As you see, I am open to any solution to this, on any level!
(The same question got deflected: How to create/enable sticky sessions in Spring Boot  But we have slow multi-threaded data production, which is not easy to incrementally persist with hibernate. Architecture change, if even possible, is not on the table!)
